# Xdebug not working in PhpStorm Ubuntu 18 PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, ubuntu-18.04

My PHP version:

[image]

My PhpStorm:

[image: PhpStorm]

/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so 
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

**When I setup remote debug (breakpoints are not working) not debugging in PhpStorm**

> I have already installed xdebug extension in Firefox

How can I fix this? Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly do you test xdebug, how deployment is organized? Would it be possible to try some really simple script with a breakpoint set on some "echo" or something like that?

I assume that you are already familiar with it, but just in case:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

> I was fixed the issue
>
> by downloaded and installed

**phpstorm new version**

now debug is working fine....